# Cleaning swap space while running

Tags: kernel, swap

I have a theoretical question,
What would happen if I clean up all the swap space while running,
Would the operating system crash because of page faults that would happen in the kernel?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean up"? Turn swap off? Overwrite with random values?

Comment: Overwrite with random values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just mean running "swapoff -a" when you say "clean up", then no.

If you corrupt/overwrite the swap device/file, an application that gets swapped back in (with corrupted data) is very likely to crash, yes. The kernel does not get swapped out, so the "system" would not crash.

Comment: The kernel does not get swapped out at all? Is it possible to configure that?

Comment: @Lee No, because the kernel does the swapping. Otherwise you would have a chicken-and-egg problem.

Answer (score 6):

Overwriting swap with random values is equivalent to overwriting process images in memory with random values.

If a *text segment* with random values is executed, the most likely result is process termination due to an *illegal instruction* (signal `SIGILL`).

If a *data segment* with random values is read, the result is most likely process termination due to a *segmentation fault* (signal `SIGSEGV`), because pointers will point outside the process's address space. Note that pointers are data, just like scalars. Especially the stack usually contains several pointers; when a *return* instruction is executed, a random stack entry causes a jump to a random address.

Comment: You refer to pointers, not content. Perhaps you can clarify that in your good answer.

Comment: @Nils Thanks for the suggestion. I've added a bit more to clarify.